# Can't disable draft & publish in strapi content type

Tags: strapi

Basically title.
When I disable draft & publish from a content type and I click on finish, I get an error message in the API ID field that tells me that "this value is already in use by another content type".

[image: error message I get]

What is causing this error? I just want to disable the draft and publish option...

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's a bug in the admin panel. You could either edit the schema.json file or disable the option while creating a new collection.

src/api/[collection]/content-types/[collection]/schema.json

```
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": false
  },
```

creating a new collection:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Changing the schema.json file worked. Is this bug known in Strapi? really gave me a headache and it was only with some collection types( couldn't really determine why as I saw no pattern)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an issue with collection names that consist of a single word, I noticed that the problem occurs when concatenating words together.